# Javafx textfield expanding to width of popup window

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using a JavaFX `Popup` window with a `TextField` inside, and I am trying to reduce the width of the `TextField`, but the `Popup` is preventing this and instead the `TextField` always grows to the width of the `Popup`.

```java
public class InputPopup extends Popup {

  public InputPopup() {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setPrefWidth(200);
    vBox.setPrefHeight(200);
    vBox.setPadding(new Insets(15));
    vBox.setSpacing(10);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Button closeBtn = new Button("Close");
    closeBtn.setOnAction(e -> this.hide());

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setMaxWidth(40.0);
    textField.setPrefWidth(40.0);
    textField.setMinWidth(40.0);

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(textField, closeBtn);
    getContent().add(vBox);
  }
}
```

I've tried using `setPrefWidth`, `setPrefSize`, `setMinSize`, `setMaxSize`. I've tried putting it inside a `HBox`. Nothing seems to work when it is inside a `Popup` window. What can I do to fix this?

EDIT

Turns out someone else in the team had pushed a css file that my code was reading from, there was a css problem that was overriding things, my code was correct but I didn't spot the css error, apologies for not spotting it, thank you for your help!

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and ran. It is working as expected. Did you modified/corrected the code?

Comment: Turns out there was a css problem that was overriding things, my code was correct but I didn't spot the css error, apologies for not spotting it, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the width and height of the `Popup` also. The other option is to use `Control.USE_PREF_SIZE`. It should work.

### Key code

```
this.setWidth(250);
this.setHeight(250);
```

or

```
this.setWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
this.setHeight(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

### Full code

### Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        InputPopup inputPopup = new InputPopup();

        Button button = new Button("Press me");
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            if (!inputPopup.isShowing()) 
                     inputPopup.show(primaryStage); 
                 else
                     inputPopup.hide(); 
        });

       Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(button), 400, 400);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Rocket");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show(); 
    }
}
```

### InputPopup

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Popup;

public class InputPopup extends Popup {

  public InputPopup() {
    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setPrefWidth(250);
    vBox.setPrefHeight(250);
    vBox.setPadding(new Insets(15));
    vBox.setSpacing(10);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Button closeBtn = new Button("Close");
    closeBtn.setOnAction(e -> this.hide());

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setMaxWidth(40.0);
    textField.setPrefWidth(40.0);
    textField.setMinWidth(40.0);

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(textField, closeBtn);
    getContent().add(vBox);
    this.setWidth(250);
    this.setHeight(250);
    vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
  }
}
```

### output

[image]